# Determine date gaps

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table that has a begin date and end date column that denote the beginning and ending range of a pricing schedule.

As the years go by, many versions of this same schedule will be created, with different beginning and ending dates.

What I would like to do is ensure that the user doesn't add, or, in some cases edit, a beginning or ending date in such a way that days would be excluded in the overall time frame.

So if the data looked like this:

```
Start      | End
-----------+--------------
01/01/2015 | 06/30/2015
07/01/2015 | 09/30/2016
10/01/2016 | 12/31/2020
```

So, lets assume I attempted to revised the last row Start to 10/15/2016. That would create a gap of days between 10/01/2016 and 10/14/2016, but I have no idea who to write a script to do this for me.  Ultimately, I would like a list of all missing dates, but even a count of days missing would be great.

Is this possible or am I approaching the issue incorrectly? Any ideas?

Using SQL Server 2012, if it matters.

Comment: Well, since each line could be independently edited, I thought I could check if any ending dates before the revised start date created a "days" gap. And this is where I started confusing myself.

select datediff(d,end_date, @beg_date) from zero_balance.dbo.dat_reimb_contract drc
where 
drc.fk_facility_id = 37 and drc.fk_audit_contract = 3000 and drc.acct_type = 'IP'
and end_date <= @beg_date
order by drc.end_date desc

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you don't want overlaps either.  So, just use `lag()` and check that it is the date before:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(end_date) over (order by start_date) as prev_end_date
      from t
     ) t
where start_date <> dateadd(day, 1, prev_end_date)
```

Comment: Can you explain how this would solve the issue of getting the missing dates?

Comment: @JamesStanich . . . This gets the rows where the previous date is not one day before the `start_date`.  That appears to be the gist of what you are asking for.

Comment: Thanks Gordon.  Not sure what I was doing wrong but it is working now.